# getting a EE template to function as a php file

Tags: templates, php

Is there a secret to getting a EE template to function as a PHP file?  I have a map that is loading the data from a php file.  I want to load the data from an EE template instead. I have set the template to allow PHP and have tried input and output but no matter what I try it will not work like I expect when I call it from a js script.

When I use a regular php file the map data loads fine.
But if I try to use a EE php template the data will not load

The php file and EE php file have the exact same data

Loading a standard php file works fine : loadData("/assets/external/data.php");
But when I take the exact same code and place it into a EE tempalte with php enabled it does nothing: loadData("http://www.domain.com/index.php/map-data");

my data.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

echo json_encode(
    $data = array(
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'latitude' => 44.5370218, 
            'longitude' => -63.6546377,
            'featured' => 1,
            'title' => " Restaurant",
            'location' => "123 Birch Street",
```

... etc

but if I copy paste the contents of that php file into an EE template and update the source for loaddata to call it from the template **it comes up with nothing to display on my map**.

The map page (that shows the actual map with data) uses a javascript. In that js file it pulls the data from data.php

I want that js file to pull the data from a php enabled EE template instead.

Here is a snippet of my JS file:

```
  if( optimizedDatabaseLoading == 1 ){
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(){
                if( searchClicked != 1 ){
                    var ajaxData = {
                        optimized_loading: 1,
                        north_east_lat: map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(),
                        north_east_lng: map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng(),
                        south_west_lat: map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat(),
                        south_west_lng: map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng()
                    };
                    if( markerCluster != undefined ){
                        markerCluster.clearMarkers();
                    }
                    //loadData("/assets/external/data.php", ajaxData);
                    loadData("http://www.physiotherapyns.ca/index.php/2017-map/map-data/", ajaxData);


                }
            });
        }
```

to highlight the relevant parts in the js file:

```
//  THIS WORKS  //
loadData("/assets/external/data.php", ajaxData);

// this does not//  
loadData("http://www.domain.com/index.php/2017-map/map-data/", ajaxData);
```

both the file and the template contain the exact same data.

**Is there anything special about the formatting of an EE template to function as a regular php file?**

Comment: Could you expand with an example of what you are trying? Are you trying to use `require` or `include` in a template to pull in another PHP file?

Comment: Ok I will do my best.  I have  standard EE template that has a google map.
To populate the map on that EE template it uses a php file.  If I use a regular data.php file the map populates.  Now if I take the exact php file and paste it into a EE template no data is populated.

Comment: What happens when you visit your data source template directly? Post the results of `curl http://www.domain.com/index.php/2017-map/map-data/`

Comment: page is blank when viewed directly.  Not sure how to post results of cURL

I tried this http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php but still a blank page

Comment: OMG problem solved (I think)  simply missing a closing  ?>  face palm..

Comment: Oooph, that will do it. That's why I suggested running the template directly; it allows you to look for errors and make sure your template isn't producing a white screen of death.

Comment: also had an issue with input/output.  Changing to output seemed to help another issue